# ML.NET Merge IDataViews in a genric way

Tags: c#, machine-learning, reflection, ml.net

I am creating a CLI tool for ML.NET and I need to make a merge function, to merge two datasets of the same type. But it needs to be as generic as possible because the tool contains different dataset types.

I managed to make a method that converts a IDataview to a generic IEnumerable with a given dataset type:

```
private IEnumerable<object> GetDataEnumerable(MLContext mlContext, IDataView dataView, Type dataViewType) {
        var createEnumerableMethod = typeof(DataOperationsCatalog).GetMethod(nameof(MLContext.Data.CreateEnumerable));
        var generic = createEnumerableMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataViewType);
        return (IEnumerable<object>)generic.Invoke(mlContext.Data, new object[] { dataView, false, null, null });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some days I figured it out. First I convert the 2 IDataviews to an IEnumerable that gets a type at runtime. After that I merge them together by converting them into Lists, and casting them to the correct type using reflection. At last I use reflection again to load the final enumerable back to a IDataview.

```
    var oldDataEnumerable = GetDataEnumerable(mlContext, oldDataView, dataViewType).ToList();
    var newDataEnumerable = GetDataEnumerable(mlContext, newDataView, dataViewType).ToList();

    var mergedEnumerable = MergeDataEnumerables(oldDataEnumerable, newDataEnumerable, dataViewType);

    return LoadEnumerableFromObject(mlContext, mergedEnumerable, dataViewType);

    private IEnumerable<object> GetDataEnumerable(MLContext mlContext, IDataView dataView, Type dataViewType) {
        var createEnumerableMethod = typeof(DataOperationsCatalog).GetMethod(nameof(MLContext.Data.CreateEnumerable));
        var generic = createEnumerableMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataViewType);
        return (IEnumerable<object>)generic.Invoke(mlContext.Data, new object[] { dataView, false, null, null });
    }

    private object MergeDataEnumerables(List<object> firstDataEnumerable, List<object> secondDataEnumerable, Type dataViewType) {
        firstDataEnumerable.AddRange(secondDataEnumerable);
        var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
        var genericCast = castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataViewType);
        var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
        var genericToList = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataViewType);
        var castedEnumerable = genericCast.Invoke(null, new[] { firstDataEnumerable });
        return genericToList.Invoke(null, new[] { castedEnumerable });
    }

    private IDataView LoadEnumerableFromObject(MLContext mlContext, object dataEnumerable, Type dataViewType) {
        var dataType = mlContext.Data.GetType();
        var loadFromEnumerableMethod = dataType.GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "LoadFromEnumerable" && m.IsGenericMethod);
        var generic = loadFromEnumerableMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataViewType);
        var schema = SchemaDefinition.Create(dataViewType);
        return (IDataView)generic.Invoke(mlContext.Data, new object[] { dataEnumerable, schema });
    }
```

Comment: You can also use generic types but that did not fit in my current architecture so I was force to use a Type parameter.